# React Native error while creating instance

Tags: react-native

I want to use Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) in React Native application; I downloaded [this](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) module and wanted to recreate first example from [this](https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/#device) site. I started with button that on press would make instance of BleManager class.

```
import { BleManager } from "react-native-ble-plx";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text
        onPress={() => {
          let manager = new BleManager();
        }}
      >
        Click
      </Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

and by pressing button I'm getting this error message:

> Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null

on my device.

Comment: Did you compile the app again after installing the new modue? You need to re-compile the app anytime you add a package with native code

Comment: Isn't it autocompile each time I click ctrl+s? I see changes immediately after doing them.

Comment: The javascript code is compiled automatically, native code no. The bluetooth module contain native code, so it must be compiled again

Comment: How do I compile native code?

Comment: How did you manage to get your app running on the device the first time? Just do it again

Comment: probably  `react-native run-android`

Comment: I started whole server again with `npm start` and I'm getting same error.

Comment: `npm start` only loads the javascript bundle. You need to perform the same operation you did to get your app running on the device. It may be `react-native run-android`, or pressing the run button on android studio, something lika that.

Comment: I'm on iOS so `react-native run-android` isn't for me (and where do I even type this?) and im coding in Visual Studio Code and not Android Studio.

Comment: Did you try react-native run-ios?

Comment: @MiłoszTomkiel tha app you are testing did not just appear on the device you are testing on. You had to perform some operation to install it there and get it running. Just perform the very same operation, I don't know what else to say. good luck

Comment: I'm using expo to get it running on my device.